# GWT ImageCell into CellTable

Tags: java, gwt

How do I put an Image cell (with >1 images) into 1 cell of a CellTable. Is it possible with gwt? 
The task is to make a selection between different images. thanks for any help or better approaches.

Comment: On what criteria/condition you want to switch between images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one article link which describe how to create custom cell with more then one images:

- [Custom GWT clickable cell with multiple images for CellTable](http://webcentersuite.blogspot.in/2011/11/custom-gwt-clickable-cell-with-multiple.html)

Hope may help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom cell. Custom cells use an HTML template, so you can implement .render() method to show your images - and other elements, if necessary.

This is a guide for creating custom cells:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells